# ¿Cómo puedo aceptar solo 1 nombre por jugador en c++?

Tags: c++

Tengo una consulta, estoy desarrollando un juego en c++ y debe ingresar 2 jugadores Sólo el nombre (sin apellido) como lo puedo hacer? he probado con getline pero no me funciona muy bien. Cómo puedo hacer que al detectar un espacio guarde lo que está antes de el en jugadorA y que despues el jugadorB digite sólo su nombre.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Hola , no muestro código porque como lo mencioné anteriormente no me ha funcionado lo que he probado ya que eso se solciita al puro inicio del juego.

Comment: No vas a encontrar un servicio de generación de código. Sí puedes recibir correcciones sobre tu código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La sobrecarga del operador de extracción para `std::string` de `cout` hace justamente eso:

```
std::string jugadorA, jugadorB;
std::cout >> jugadorA >> jugadorB;
```

Ante una entrada tipo

```
Laura Ruben
```

`jugadorA` almacenará el valor `Laura` y `jugadorB` se quedará con `Ruben`

Obtendrás el mismo resultado si en vez de un espacio usas 600 o si introduces un salto de línea.

Otra cosa es que necesites validar que el usuario no ha introducido un espacio. En ese caso sí que deberías usar `getline` para, a continuación, comprobar que no hay espacios en el string leído:

```
std::string jugadorA;

while(true)
{
    std::getline(std::cin, jugadorA);

    if (jugadorA.find(' ') == std::string::npos)
        break;
}
```